# How to access proxy details (socks and http) in the application?

Tags: android, http, proxy, socks

How to access proxy details from phone to application by coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the above question by using the sample app- APL demo

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lechucksoftware.proxy.lib.activities&hl=en

Source code is available from-

https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy-library-demo